# Making a First person camera

Tags: java, matrix, camera, lwjgl

So I have a problem when I try to make a first person camera.
I searched some tutorials and all of them use `glRotatef` or `glTranslate`
And when I run using those two methods I get a error:

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdESw.png)

So how can I make a first person camera without calling those two methods

- I have a working camera class using matrices.

Comment: "is not supported" ... either you are looking at out of date tutorials, or you are using the wrong version(s) of the framework(s)

Comment: Im using Lwjgl 2.9

Comment: what version was used by those who made the tutorial?

Comment: Well Im not sure but I tried this tutorial: http://www.lloydgoodall.com/tutorials/first-person-camera-control-with-lwjgl/

Comment: All older versions of OpenGL should be supported via compatibility layers in graphics drivers, although I'm sure there are some that don't. To be sure, what does "System.out.println("OpenGL version: " + GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION));" print out in your game?

Comment: It prints this: OpenGL version: 3.3.13399 Core Profile Forward-Compatible Context 15.200.1062.1004, I tried other versions and it didn't work